# Displaying “Related Products” in a custom tab for normal single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce, I have this code below for adding "Related Products" to a custom tab and making it work on posts that are used with a short code **`[product_page id="99"]`** on pages and posts.

The code that I use in functions.php that is working:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
/*
 * Register custom tab
 */
function woo_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $custom_tab = array( 
        'custom_tab' =>  array( 
            'title' => __('Custom Tab','woocommerce'), 
            'priority' => 9, 
            'callback' => 'woo_custom_product_tab_content' 
        )
    );
    return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab' );

/*
* Place content in custom tab (related products in this sample)
*/
function woo_custom_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    $product->get_related();
}
```

Now the problem is that I get a blank tab in normal product single pages.

How can I make it work on normal product single pages too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work also on single product pages you need to add some conditions and to reuse the **`woocommerce_related_products()`** just for single product pages.

So your code will be now:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
/*
 * Register custom tab
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab', 20, 1 );
function woo_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $custom_tab = array( 
        'custom_tab' =>  array( 
            'title' => __('Custom Tab','woocommerce'), 
            'priority' => 9, 
            'callback' => 'woo_custom_product_tab_content' 
        )
    );
    return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}

/*
* Place content in custom tab (related products in this sample)
*/
function woo_custom_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    if(!is_product())
        $product->get_related();
    else
        woocommerce_related_products();
}
```

This should work for your product shortcode on pages and post on one side and also on single woocommerce normal product pages.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate all your WooCommerce knowledge! you've been very helpful on a various amount of questions!